# How to get all orders except the ones with specific status

Tags: magento-1.9, collection, filter, magento-1.9.2.1

I am using `Magento 1.9.2` and i am working on a custom extension.

Here is what code i use to select all orders with specific status:

```
<?php $_orders = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('status', 'complete'); ?>
```

How can i select all orders except the ones with specific status?

Here is the complete code of the .phtml where i use the code shown above:

```
<?php echo $this->getMessagesBlock()->getGroupedHtml() ?>
<?php $_orders = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('status', 'complete') ?>
<div class="page-title">
    <h1><?php echo $this->__('My Orders') ?></h1>
</div>
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('info');?>
<?php echo $this->getPagerHtml(); ?>
<?php if($_orders->getSize()): ?>
<table class="data-table orders" id="my-orders-table">
    <col width="1" />
    <col width="1" />
    <col />
    <col width="1" />
    <col width="1" />
    <col width="1" />
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="number"><?php echo $this->__('Order #') ?></th>
            <th class="date"><?php echo $this->__('Date') ?></th>
            <th class="ship"><?php echo $this->__('Ship To') ?></th>
            <th class="total"><span class="nobr"><?php echo $this->__('Order Total') ?></span></th>
            <th class="status"><span class="nobr"><?php echo $this->__('Order Status') ?></span></th>
            <th class="view">&nbsp;</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <?php $_odd = ''; ?>
        <?php foreach ($_orders as $_order): ?>
        <tr>
            <td class="number"><?php echo $_order->getRealOrderId() ?></td>
            <td class="date"><span class="nobr"><?php echo $this->formatDate($_order->getCreatedAtStoreDate()) ?></span></td>
            <td class="ship"><?php echo $_order->getShippingAddress() ? $this->escapeHtml($_order->getShippingAddress()->getName()) : '&nbsp;' ?></td>
            <td class="total"><?php echo $_order->formatPrice($_order->getGrandTotal()) ?></td>
            <td class="status"><em><?php echo $_order->getStatusLabel() ?></em></td>
            <td class="a-center view">
                <span class="nobr"><a href="<?php echo $this->getViewUrl($_order) ?>"><?php echo $this->__('View Order') ?></a>
                    <?php /*<span class="separator">|</span><a href="<?php echo $this->getTrackUrl($_order) ?>"><?php echo $this->__('Track Order') ?></a>&nbsp;*/ ?>
                    <?php if ($this->helper('sales/reorder')->canReorder($_order)) : ?>
                    <span class="separator">|</span> <a href="<?php echo $this->getReorderUrl($_order) ?>" class="link-reorder"><?php echo $this->__('Reorder') ?></a>
                <?php endif ?>
                </span>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
<script type="text/javascript">decorateTable('my-orders-table');</script>
<?php echo $this->getPagerHtml(); ?>
<?php else: ?>
    <p><?php echo $this->__('You have placed no orders.'); ?></p>
<?php endif ?>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: what status of orders you dont want ?

Comment: Yes i want to not show orders with a specific status of `epaycc`. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6):

you can use `neq`

```
<?php $_orders = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('status',array('neq' => 'complete')); ?>
```

as your request status `epaycc`

```
<?php $_orders =   Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('status',array('neq' => 'epaycc')); ?>
```

Comment: Seems to be not working.

Comment: I have updated my question.

Comment: update the answer too.

Comment: Again not working...

Comment: I receive a blank page without any errors.

Comment: it mean your page have a php error that are stop execute the page go to `index.php` and remove `#` from `#ini_set('display_errors', 1);`